# Asynchronous python script execution from button

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, cgi

I have a pretty standard LAMP installation on an RPi.

I have an html interface with indicators and buttons. I am using Jquery to read server-side text files into indicators, and would like to have buttons adjust the indicators.

My implementation is a form with buttons that run a python script via cgi. The idea is to have python scripts edit the file that the jquery is reading into indicators. Other scripts run on the server that read the text file into hardware control, so this intermediate file is important.

The problem is that the python script execution redirects the page. I just need the script to execute quietly.

Thanks.
C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here is either cgi or wsgi via a pretty trivial ajax call. It's funny to look back at this question, in retrospect.

The jquery, in this case to execute a query on a sqlite database:

```
function wsgiCallbackTableData (database,table,callback) {
    // Get the data
    //alert(database + ' ' + table + ' ' + callback)
    $.ajax({
        url: "/wsgisqlitequery",
        type: "post",
        datatype:"json",                        
        data: {'database':database,'table':table},
        success: function(response){
            //alert("I worked");
            // Execute our callback function
            callback(response);                                     
        }
     });    
}
```

The python:

```
def application(environ, start_response):

import cgi
import json
from pilib import dynamicsqliteread, sqlitequery

post_env = environ.copy()
post_env['QUERY_STRING'] = ''
post = cgi.FieldStorage(
    fp=environ['wsgi.input'],
    environ=post_env,
    keep_blank_values=True
)

formname=post.getvalue('name')
data={}
d={}
for k in post.keys():
    d[k] = post.getvalue(k)

status = '200 OK'

# Run stuff as requested

if 'length' in d:                   # Handle table row subset
    data=dynamicsqliteread(d['database'],d['table'],d['start'],d['length'])
elif 'row' in d:                    # Handle table row
    data=dynamicsqliteread(d['database'],d['table'],d['row'])

elif 'table' in d:                  # Handle entire table
    data=dynamicsqliteread(d['database'],d['table'])
elif 'query' in d:                          # Take plain single query
    result=sqlitequery(d['database'],d['query'])
    data=result
elif 'queryarray[]' in d:           # Take query array, won't find
    result=[]
    for query in d['queryarray[]']:
        result.append(sqlitequery(d['database'],query))
    data=result
else:
    data=['empty']

output = json.dumps(data,indent=1)

response_headers = [('Content-type', 'application/json')]
start_response(status,response_headers)

return [output]
```

pilib contains a pretty basic set of sqlite commands packed into a dynamic call.